# Orphan boy hunts demons on the side while at demon-hunting school

Tags: story-identification, manga, demons

Manga about an orphan boy who went to a demon hunting school while making money on the side with a group that hunts demons off campus. An evil former student's spirit from the boy's school tried to take over the boy's body but ends up in the body of a little demon cat. The evil spirit became a guide for the boy. The boy befriended a girl that he doesn't know is a demon.

Comment: [Demon Hunting Academy](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/w5fobbk/lie-yao-xue-yuan)?

Comment: Do you know when this student ends up as a demon cat? Or if the boy starts hunting demons before going to school, immediately upon starting school, or sometime after starting school? Blue Exorcist seems like a decent match and has the "cat(s)" tag, but those specific events haven't happened 3 chapters in.